# Axios not making request, no result, no error

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a problem with an axios put request in vue2
the following code is used to save an update form.

there are 2 flows in which this method is called.

1. you click on a organisation, the window.location.hash is changed to the organisationId the user fills the form and clicks on save
2. the user goes to the page with the organisations with an window.location.hash in the url (#1 (#id)) the user fills in the form and click on save

code:

```
/**
 * Handle the update form.
 *
 * @param {array} selected
 * @return {Promise}
 */
update(selected) {
    this.$refs.updateForm.validate();
    console.log('1');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('2');
        if (this.updateForm.valid) {
            console.log('3');
            this.$http
                .put('organisation/' + selected[0].id, this.updateForm.values)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('10');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('NO');
                    console.log(error)
                });
            console.log('4');
        }
    });
},
```

---

Results:
in case 1 everything works, console.log:

```
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:135 1
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:138 2
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:140 3
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:151 4
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:144 10
```

---

in case 2 it doesn't work, the request isn't made, console.log:

```
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:136 1
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:138 2
OrganisationResource.vue?2497:140 3
```

> Also in case 2, a console.log in the axios request interceptor is not
>   triggered. And when after flow 2, you start flow 1 without a page refresh, it works perfectly

I also have no clue how I can debug this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether `selected[0]` & `this.updateForm` are defined. Otherwise the access to it will throw, so neither the `then` nor the `catch` of axios will be called.

Comment: `this.updateForm` is definitely defined because `if (this.updateForm.valid) {` would throw and `console.log(3)` would not log. Strange that OP does not see the error but can see the log. Maybe there is a filter on what the console shows (no errors).

Comment: there where indeed errors inside the promise. The reject was called, except the snackbar diddn't show up, which is why i diddnt thought about that. Thanks for your help here and in the chat

Comment: @HMR true, didn't think about the if clause at this moment, so probably `selected[0]` it is

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, it reflects what your code is doing even though it doesn't make a whole lot of sense:

```
/**
 * Handle the update form.
 *
 * @param {array} selected
 * @return {Promise}
 */
update(selected) {
  return Promise.resolve()//switch to native promises
  .then(
    ()=>{
      //any error will be caught with the .catch, no unprotected code
      //  function will always return a promise that resolves to undefined
      this.$refs.updateForm.validate();
      console.log('1');
      console.log('2');
      if (this.updateForm.valid) {
        console.log('3');
        return this.$http
          .put('organisation/' + selected[0].id, this.updateForm.values);
      }//return undefined if not valid
    }
  ).then(result => {
      console.log('10');//resolve with undefined if valid or invalid without error
  }).catch(
    error => {//resolve to undefined with error
      console.log('NO');
      console.log(error)
  });
  console.log('4');
},
```

Without the use of native promises you could use `return this.$q.resolve()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The code indeed doesn't make much sence, but i'm definitely going to try this in the feature

Comment: @RicardovanLaarhoven I updated the answer, no need to use native promises, you can support more browsers (Internet Explorer) without having to polyfil since angular already has a polyfil for promises.